# How to inflate a view properly in Kotlin with View Binding

Tags: android, view

I created a custom view as this:

```
class CustomView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {

   val textView: TextView
   val button: Button
   
    init {
        ViewCustomBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context)).apply {
            this.textView = textView
            this.button = button
        }
    }
```

This is for a custom view that has a `TextView` and a `Button`. However, when this is inflated as a view in any layout, I do not see the view being inflated. I am wondering what is missing in this code that actually inflates this view on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've never added the view you inflated to the hierarchy. You can either add it with

```
addView(binding.root)
```

or pass your view as the parent in the `inflate` method.

---

Edit

I've just noticed your custom view inherits from the `View` class which can't act as a parent to other views. You should be using some subclass of `ViewGroup`.

Comment: I see, I'll try to make it:  
`class CustomView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs)` and the init to `ViewCustomBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context, this, true))`

Comment: That works! So the learning is to always extend ViewGroups whenever there are multiple view in the custom view! Thanks.